# How to use an existing sqlalchemy Enum in an Alembic migration (Postgres)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

At some point in the past I've run an alembic migration which creates a `users` table like...

```py
def upgrade():
    ...
    op.create_table(
        "users",
        sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
        ...
        sa.Column("type", sa.Enum("Foo", "Bar", "Baz", name="usertype"), nullable=False),
        ...
    )
    ...
```

...which automatically creates the enum named `usertype` with the values `"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"`.

Now, I want to make some other table which also references that same enum. e.g.,

```py
def upgrade():
    ...
    op.create_table('foobar',
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
        ...
        sa.Column('user_type', sa.Enum(< ???????? >), nullable=False),
        ...
    )
```

What is the syntax to reference the **existing** enum?

I can't seem to find an answer in the docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum

Answer (score 34):

There are two parts to make this happen with Postgres.

1. Specify `create_type=False`
2. Use [`sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM) (not `sqlalchemy.Enum`)

Eg:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

sa.Column('my_column', postgresql.ENUM(name='my_enum', create_type=False))
```

Comment: Can the enum's values be obtained through introspection so they don't need to be repeated in the migration?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think you may be able to omit the enum values: `postgresql.ENUM(name='my_enum', create_type=False)`.

Comment: Looks like you can, will update my answer

Answer (score 5):

You might need to pass enum object instead of its name as string.

```py
    entity = Column(
        postgresql.ENUM(
            SocialType,
            create_type=False,
            checkfirst=True,
            inherit_schema=True,
        )
    )
```

`checkfirst=True` and `create_type=False` doesn't get detected by alembic. So you need to add it manually.  Finally, alembic migration should look like

```
sa.Column('entity', postgresql.ENUM('github', 'twitter', name='socialtype', schema='dashboard', inherit_schema=True, create_type=False, checkfirst=True), nullable=True),
```

Comment: that's what I found too - create_type is ignored by alembic.

Answer (score -1):

For a simple, effective, and backend agnostic solution to this problem [please see my answer in another thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73861502/6163904)

Answer (score -3):

Couldn't find much information on how to fix this error but here is what you need to do.

after you autogenerated the migration just add create_type=False, to the enum field in the migration file.

```
sa.Column('user_type', sa.Enum(< ???????? >, create_type=False), nullable=False),
```

Comment: sa.Enum does not have that keyword argument.