# How to use existing postgres enum in alembic migration?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a new migration using alembic. My database has a enum name `myenum`.

This is the migration script:

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        "test_table",
        # ...
        sa.Column("enum_col", sa.Enum("A", "B", "C", name="myenum"), server_default="A", nullable=False)
        # ...
    )
```

But when I migrate the script, it excepts:

> DuplicateObject: "myenum" already exists

I need to know how to use the existing enum in migration.

I've tried `create_type=False` as shown in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65875096/5611227). But It doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `Enum` type of SQLAlchemy doesn't support `create_type`. You can use the `ENUM` type from the postgres dialect which support `create_type=False`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql as pg
def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        "test_table",
        # ...
        sa.Column("enum_col", 
                  pg.ENUM("A", "B", "C", 
                  name="myenum", create_type=False), 
                  server_default="A", nullable=False)
        # ...
    )
```

See the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM.params.create_type) for some additional information about `create_type`.